# How to generate hbm.xml file from FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbmxml

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/10/19/using-fluent-Nhibernate-to-Export-Create-hbm-files-(Nhibernate-mapping-files).aspx) but instead of generating the expected hbm.xml files with my mappings in it generates simple .cs class for my entities like for example:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
```

But I already defined those myself in code. I'm after the .hbm.xml which I can use in standard NHibernate at this time.

This is how I set up the SessionFactory:

```
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        String schemaExportPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Mappings");

        if (!Directory.Exists(schemaExportPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(schemaExportPath);


        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c =>c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionString"))
                .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache()
                    .ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>()).ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>().ExportTo(schemaExportPath))
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).SetOutputFile(@"c:\temp\test.sql").Create(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See : [Fluent_Configuration](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration#Exporting_mappings), the last section of the page.

It shows this code

```
.Mappings(m =>
{
  m.FluentMappings
    .AddFromAssemblyOf<YourEntity>()
    .ExportTo(@"C:\your\export\path");

  m.AutoMappings
    .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<YourEntity>(type => type.Namspace.EndsWith("Entities")));)
    .ExportTo(@"C:\your\export\path");
})
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me. I only still get the .cs files. Not the hbm.xml ones. What exactly needs to go in the Add method? I left it out for now.

Comment: If you look at the previous example.. it shows this in the add method

 AutoMap.AssemblyOf<YourEntity>(type => type.Namspace.EndsWith("Entities")));

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll take a look at it tomorrow morning (don't have the code here at home).

Comment: For some reason I tried again with leaving the automappings part out of it, rebuilding the solution and trying again and they appeared. I marked your answer as such. Thanks for your time.